# Find all number-literals in a solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there a way to search for all the number-literals in a solution?

So for example these will be included:

```
Margin = new Thickness(10);
int i = 10;
```

And these not:

```
Margin = margin123;
int i100 = j100;
```

Comment: Does it means you want to get all rows in source code where only nubers are used for any coomand? What should be final output?

Comment: @VitezslavSimon No. The line can have other stuff in it as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try enabling `match whole word` option along side with regex `(\d)*`

Answer (score 0):

Not so effective solution but possible is working too:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly char[] numbers = new char[] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
        static readonly char[] allowedChars = new char[] {'(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', ' '};
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string input = @"
Margin = new Thickness(10);
int i = 10;
Margin = margin123;
int i100 = j100;
a10
124b
";
            List<string> matches = new List<string>();
            foreach (var row in input.Split('\n')) 
            {
                int start = row.IndexOfAny(numbers);
                
                if (start == -1) 
                    continue;
                
                if (start == 0 || numbers.Contains(row[start - 1]) || allowedChars.Contains(row[start - 1]))
                {
                    matches.Add(row);
                } 
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n\r", matches));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Margin = new Thickness(10);
int i = 10;
124b
```

Comment: @ispiro was trying to find number-literals in the solution (in the code itself), not in a string.